# Position of ads on an android app

Tags: android, layout, libgdx, admob

I have a libgdx game and I successfully put ads in it but I have one problem

The Ads covers the bottom part of screen where I have some important stuff

My question is How can I put both views (gameView and adView) so that they don't overlap each other ?

Here is AndroidLauncher class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {

    protected AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(this), config);
        layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
        adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void showBannerAd() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                adView.loadAd(builder.build());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void hideBannerAd() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean showAds() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (ni != null && ni.isConnected());
    }
}
```

Here is AdsController interface

```
public interface AdsController {

    public void showBannerAd();
    public void hideBannerAd();
    public boolean showAds();

}
```

and one more thing I want my game to take the full screen size if there is no internet connection (no ads).

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game View needs layout params that set it above the AdView. Therefore, it needs RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, not just ViewGroup.LayoutParams. With this kind of layout, you can cause the game to fill the whole screen by setting the AdView's visibility to `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`. So you can just leave it gone until an ad is available.

To set it in relation to the other view, you need to give the other view an ID, which you can generate with `View.generateViewId()`.

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(this), config);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
        adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        int adViewId = View.generateViewId();
        adView.setId(adViewId);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        gameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, adViewId);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);
        layout.addView(gameView, gameParams);

        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

Comment: You mean I don't need showBannerAd() and hideBannerAd() methods

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do. You might want to have those to hide the ad during gameplay. But if you just want to show ads all the time, you don't really need those. What you should add is an AdListener for your AdView that sets its visibility to either GONE or VISIBLE based on whether an ad is now showing (`onAdLoaded` vs. `onAdFailedToLoad`).